# Gauss-seidel and implicit method

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and I want to apply a function $f_{ij}$ to each entry of it, until convergence is satisfied. If a value is known in this matrix, then the $f_{ij}$ at this point may be the identity function. I was wondering if there exists a way to convert this Gauss-Seidel approach, an iterative approach, to an implicit method. Given matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and functions $f_{ij}$ and knowing I want the system to converge, to make a system $$A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$$
where $\mathbf{b}$ are known coefficients and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector will all the elements of matrix $\mathbf{X}$ properly ordered, as $x_1=X_{11}$, $x_2=X_{12}$, $x_3=X_{13}$..$x_n=X_{1n}$, $x_{1+n}=X_{21}$..$x_{n^2}=X_{nn}$.

I have been thinking of that problem and trying to find something on internet, but I am not successful up to this moment.
My idea is to use it to solve some differential equations using finite differences. Particularly I have been thinking of Poisson with pure Neumann conditions, and maybe this would be useful for other equations that I will have to solve. By the way, $f_{ij}$ are probably linear functions, but they depend on elements of matrix $\mathbf{X}$. For example, I may have $f_{11}=X_{12}-0.25X_{13}$, $f_{22}=X_{12}+X_{32}+X_{21}+X_{23}$. I may have functions basically taking values of the neighborhood to define the value at the point.